# How to stop users from choosing inappropriate Profile name

Tags: discussion

I have seen many users on other platform in which they setup there profile name in a way so that whoever will read their profile name, they surely feel insulting. I have found one here also that's why I am raising this issue here.

What they actually do is, they write profile name in their native language so that foreigners couldn't grab the meaning. But the actual meaning of profile name is something like: directly insulting your family. For example, the username I found today:

> your-bhehnoi

His profile name is `Your Bhehnoi`. Now the problematic word here is "`Bhehnoi`". The meaning of this word is "`Sister's Husband`". Now if we see his actual profile name in understandable language then This is his profile name "`Your Sister's Husband`". Now you all can guess what he is actually trying to say to all of us with his profile name.

This is totally unacceptable because he is directly targeting our family for no reason. We all have sisters and if someone say about our sisters something like that then how do we feel? While targeting our sisters he didn't even think that someone's sister might be of only 10 or 15 year old and some must be married also. And if someone is saying something like this then this must be stop.

I don't know what's the solution of this problem but this is a problem and moreover this is that kind of problem who can't be find out that easily, means if someone uses his/her native language to give us abusive comment in form of profile name then not everyone can figure out what's the meaning of profile name except those who knows same language. Many users must have seen this profile name here but no one could grab the meaning, hence this issue becomes very hard to find. We can't get to know what some users are doing on site since we don't know all languages of the word. I could get the meaning of his profile name only because we speak same language and I know the meaning of this word.

I tried to make him convince about changing his name but he didn't agree and start getting personal in comment section and refused to change his name.

This is just one profile that came in my notice only because I know the language in which it was written BUT who knows how many users are in this site who are using native language with the intention of insulting other!

If anyone have any Idea/solution regarding this problem then please share.

Comment: Just ignore him :)

Answer (score 7):

## Future reference / readers

A better way to report a possibly offensive username or user behavior is to flag one of the users posts with the [`Moderator Intervention`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86623/322985) option describing the issue in the given textbox. This will ensure it reaches a moderator and keeps anonymity from the offending user.

---

The username is not necessarily obscene or widely offensive. There are certain usernames which we would deem unsuitable for display but I wouldn't classify this as one of them. If the username was more explicit then it would be cause for alarm but it's mild at best. It's not targeted at a specific person but a general audience for their own amusement which shouldn't be taken personally.

If a name is widely offensive or unnecessarily obscene we can take action and talk with the user or force a name change but I do not believe this is a necessary action here.

Comment: But this might be just beginning step for these kinds of users. With time they can get more aggressive or abusive since no one is pointing out them.

Comment: At lease one warning should be given to them so they can understand this site is not like other sites that can tolerate these kinds of name.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention, and you can always bring questionable names to [The Loop chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop). There's no need for a warning in this case because as my answer states, it's not overly offensive or obscene. If usernames get out of hand then actions would be taken at that point.

Comment: Alright then, I guess response to my question may vary from country to country. Means In my country we takes these kinds of comments totally unacceptable But in other country this might not be a very big deal because every country's way of thinking and view points of seeing different issue is different because of their different culture and different lifestyle. So if you consider this as no issue then I can understand :)